# calling object's properties using super (or how to access super view button in a sub view)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have main view with a button sub view
StartScene.h:

```
@class PlayScene
@interface StartScene : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    PlayScene* tView;
    UIButton *Ok;
}
```

somewhere in StartScene.m:

```
Ok = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[Ok setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 190, 65, 30)];
[Ok setTitle:(NSString *)@"OK" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
[Ok addTarget:self action:@selector(gameOverDidLoad) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self addSubview:Ok];

Ok.hidden=YES;
Ok.enabled=NO;

tView = [[PlayScene alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];
tView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGround.jpg"]];
[self addSubview:tView];
```

and sub view:
PlayScene.h:

```
#import "StartScene.h"
@interface PlayScene : StartScene {
}
```

PlayScene.m:

```
- (void)ooneFingerTwoTaps {
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(oneFingerTwoTaps) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

is called and method for it is

```
 - (void)oneFingerTwoTaps
{
//  some code
    if (self.GameState==GameLost) {
        [super checkScore:xScore];
        Ok.hidden=NO;
        Ok.enabled=YES;

        [[NSThread currentThread] cancel];
        }
    }
}
```

so need Ok button to appear when something happens in PlayScene.

I've tried

```
Ok.hidden=NO;
Ok.enabled=YES;
```

But it doesn't work. I guess, due to the fact that child view can see only an UIButton variable, that is not yet initialized.

So I got 2 questions here:

1) I can call Ok variable using self.Ok or super.Ok . I thought that super.Ok would totally work but I don't know and I can't find out the right syntax here. What is it?

2) May be the problem can be solved in some other way?

Comment: This code is obviously heavily edited at least. This code isn't even syntactically valid — you can't send messages in a global context. If we have to make extensive guesses to even make your code compile, that means we're going to have to either get very lucky with a guess or play 20 questions to figure out what your real code looks like.  The easier you make answering your question, the better the answers you'll get.